# SQL Server 2008 prefixing database name to the table/view name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a database using a SQL script. The database was created correctly but the problem is that the script prefixed the database name before all tables/views name.

If for ex. database name is `ABC` and table name is `TableName` then script named it as `ABC.TableName`. Now whenever I want to refer to that table in programming I have to use `ABC.TableName`

Is there any way so that I can remove that prefix from all tables/view or instead of database name prefix use `dbo` prefix  for ex. in this case `dbo.TableName`. Also I don't want to lose any data in the table

Comment: I don't believe you. If `ABC` was database name, it would be `ABC..TableName`

Comment: The `abc` is the name of the **schema** inside your database - not the database name itself

Comment: What you're asking is somewhat unclear but I believe what you are looking to achieve can be done with [SYNONYMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following at the top of the script to switch to database ABC:

```
USE ABC
GO
```